# Panel Events not firing? (C#)

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008

I have a Form and I have some defined methods that are different from the standard events provided by winforms. I have a panel overlaying my form and I want to add custom mouse_up and mouse_down events.

What I've tried (which works for the form but not for the outer panel) is:

```
public Form1() 
{ 
    InitializeComponent();

    OuterPanel.MouseUp += delegate(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) { OnMouseEvent_UpDown(sender, e, "custom param"); };
    OuterPanel.MouseDown += delegate(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) { OnMouseEvent_UpDown(sender, e, "custom param"); };
}
```

where OuterPanel is the name of the panel which overlays my main form. When I switch "OuterPanel.event += OnEvent(args)" to "this.event += OnEvent(args)" and remove the panel entirely, I get the functionality that I want.

Comment: What do you mean with *a panel overlaying my form*? What kind of Control is this? What is the problem (what *doesn't work*)? The event is not triggered?

Comment: @Jimi I have created a panel that i resize to take up all the space within the boundary of my form. I want to do all drawing on this panel. I specify the panel in the designer (not in code), but I want to add event handlers to it as shown above.

Comment: @Jimi and when I run my code nothing happens when I click up or down

Comment: *when I click up or down*? Meaning? You're referring to a Mouse click, right? A Mouse click on the surface of this Control.

Comment: @Jimi Yes, specifically a MouseUp and MouseDown event. I have defined a method which takes parameters different than the standard method and as such wanted to provide the event methods at run time. If I could just use the standard that would be great but I am trying this as an exercise

Comment: The event handlers that you provided are correct. That's not the issue. See that the handlers are wired to the correct Control and that this Control can be clicked. Post the code that resizes the Panel. Verify that you don't have any `new OuterPanel();` somewhere (or something like that). Or maybe you have docked a child Control inside this Panel

Comment: I solved it. I was using the Form.createGraphics() method instead of specifying the control that triggered the event

Comment: Well, good job then :) Btw, never use `Control.CreateGraphics()` to draw on the surface of a control. Use the Graphics object provided by the control's `Paint` event's `PaintEventArgs`.